# an two different bases be used when calculating the determinant of a linear map from V to V?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am trying to create a matrix for a linear map from V to V and calculate the determinant. This would be way easier if I could use two different bases on the horizontal and vertical directions, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Can I do this?

Comment: It depends. You’re looking at a linear transformation $f:V\to V$. For *some* purposes you may use different bases in the domain and the codomain. Are you interested only in the zeroness/nonzeroness of the determinant? In this case, yes. If, on the other hand, you are interested in the specific nonzero numerical value of the determinant, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

To choose a basis is to choose an isomorphism $\phi : V \to \Bbb R^n$. Then the matrix $M$ is the linear map defined by $M = \phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1}$, and
$$\begin{align}\det M &= \det(\phi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})\\
&=(\det \phi)(\det f)(\det \phi^{-1})\\
&=(\det f)(\det \phi)(\det \phi)^{-1}\\
&=\det f\end{align}$$

But suppose you use a different isomorphism $\psi$ for one of the conversions:
$$\begin{align}\det M &= \det(\psi\circ f\circ \phi^{-1})\\
&=(\det \psi)(\det f)(\det \phi^{-1})\\
&=(\det f)(\det \psi)(\det \phi)^{-1}\end{align}$$

But there is no guarantee that $(\det \psi)(\det \phi)^{-1} = 1$. Both values are non-zero, since the maps are isomorphisms, but that is all we can say. Because they are non-zero, $\det M = 0 \iff \det f = 0$, but we cannot conclude that $\det M = \det f$.